# cannot reindex invalid index "public.model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew" concurrently, skipping

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

We have postgresql 12v.Weekly purging script on production will run on few tables, on one table after purging/vacuum the table, reindex is failing and creating one new copy with invalid index. Due to this index size increased to 300Gb.

Please find indexes details on table and tell me the steps to fix this issue.
Indexes:
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew1" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew2" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew3" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew4" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew5" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew6" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"model_recommendation_association_pkey_new_ccnew7" UNIQUE, btree (id) INVALID
"mod_recomm" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew2_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew2_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew3_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew3_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew4" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew5" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew1_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew2_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew2_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew3_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew3_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew4" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew5" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew2_ccnew_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id)
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew1_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew1_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew2" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew3" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew_ccnew" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID
"mod_recomm_ccnew3_ccnew_ccnew1" btree (recommendation_id) INVALID

Comment: Drop all the invalid indexes and edit your question with the complete error message from `REINDEX`.

Comment: I doubt REINDEX is making a new copy, something else in your script is probably doing that.

Comment: What is your complete version number from `select version()`

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit

Comment: The script is tested and scheduled. This is not new script and it is working fine

Comment: Hi Laurenz, After dropping invalid index we need to use reindex on index. If reindex fails on index  saying next what i need to do.

Comment: Plz anyone provide the steps, this issue on prod server